# Import from CSV into MySQL - different lines into different tables

Tags: mysql, csv

I have a single csv file with data that I am trying to load into MySQL using LOAD DATA. My problem is the csv file has data that belongs in 3 separate tables. Line 1 goes into table1, line 2-3 goes into table 2, and all remaining lines go into table 3. I can use IGNORE 3 LINES for the 3rd table, but not sure how to ignore lines after my required data for the first 2 tables.

Here is my LOAD DATA so far:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.csv' INTO TABLE tbl_name1
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';

LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.csv' INTO TABLE tbl_name2
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  IGNORE 1 LINES;

LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.csv' INTO TABLE tbl_name3
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  IGNORE 3 LINES;
```

Comment: I would load all the lines into one table, then copy subsets of rows into the proper tables, then drop the initial load table.

Comment: Another solution is to split the CSV file into three files before you load them into the respective tables.

Comment: If minor editing of the file is acceptable, you could prefix the first line with one string, and the second two with a different one, and use the `STARTING BY` clause for the `LOAD` calls for those lines of data... or just split the csv into three separate files.

Comment: I have to do it without changing the CSV file. I guess loading it into one table then copying sections over to their proper home is the best solution. Thanks!